# JSON httprequest syntax

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, getjson

i have a JSON function that calls a url and show it's content in a prompt msg, the function works i tested it whith this url : http://date.jsontest.com/

but I have to do a url that has this content : // this is a java file a class

```
reponse_tex="{ id:" + p_id + ",Categorie: "+ p_demandAide.getP_categorie()+ ",Type: " +p_demandAide.getP_type() +",Message: " +p_demandAide.getP_message()+",Reponse: " +p_demandAide.getP_response() + " }";
```

my class works, and it shows me the content in the browser , but i know i must write it in a format so that json understand it just like the first example url... 
but it's quite hard for me to add the ("") java don't allowd it in it"s syntax.

Comment: what do you mean java won't allow it? DO you mean you have to escape it?

Comment: it gives me syntax error when i want to add the ("")

Comment: @nuestre can you post what it looks like? or is it the one above?

Comment: in the browser it shows me : 
{id:some,Categorie: cat1,Type: type1,Message: alert,Reponse: hi}

Comment: @nuestre So the output in the console is that, with a syntax error? And I do not know where you are using the (""), as for the java file store it in a variable as oppose to the //

Comment: no, I have a json function that calls a url and show it's content, my function works with the url i posted because the url has a content that is fimiliar to json .it's syntax is knowen by json . But me my content that shows like this : 
{id:some,Categorie: cat1,Type: type1,Message: alert,Reponse: hi} 

is not known by JSON  , i must add the "" like the first url... but this is a java class and i don't know how to add it, when i add it it gives me syntax error in the class.

Comment: @nuestre so you want something like this `"{ "id":" + p_id + ` notice id is in quotes.

Comment: yes , but i want also that p-id and other variables be in quotes ..

Comment: and when i do like that : "{ "id":" + p_id +  .. it says to me multiple markers at this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is very clear about syntax. See http://www.json.org/  You need double quotes around both string values *and* key names. `{"like": "this", "see?": true}` (If you need a double quote in a string value, you escape with backslash: `{"this": "has \"literal\" quotes"}`)

As for writing a string literal in Java that has double quotes in it, you escape them with backslash `"like \"this\", see?"`

Comment: np! i really do find that flowchart (on json.org) to be a nice visual reference.

Comment: one other thing that can easily catch you is trailing commas. unlike in python (for example), `{"this": "is NOT valid",}`

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you are looking to escape the the quote. So do this

```
reponse_tex="{\"id\":\"" + p_id + "\",\"Categorie\": \""+ 
p_demandAide.getP_categorie()+ "\",\"Type\": \"" +p_demandAide.getP_type() 
+"\",\"Message\": \"" +p_demandAide.getP_message()+"\",\"Reponse\": \"" 
+p_demandAide.getP_response() + "\" }";
```

**Update**

Escaped the quote around the key too ex. \"id\" ...
notice the difference if I do not escape the quote id, catagorie is no longer aprt of the string

```
reponse_tex="{"id":\"" + p_id + "\","Categorie": \""+ 
p_demandAide.getP_categorie()+ "\","Type\": "" +p_demandAide.getP_type() 
+"\","Message": \"" +p_demandAide.getP_message()+"\","Reponse": \"" 
+p_demandAide.getP_response() + "\" }";
```

Comment: @nuestre LOL escape the quote between id and etc too